# Get multiple features from WMS

Tags: wms, getfeatureinfo

I am trying to retrieve more than one feature from a WMS service. I had success on some by using a combination of feature_count and setting the width and height to 2 with a x/y value of 1. But on some, this seems to not work. (WFS is not available)

Here an example where I am getting just one feature:

https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/alkis_wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&QUERY_LAYERS=adv_alkis_flurstuecke&VERSION=1.3.0&BBOX=33342364.68195192515850067,5974549.42051891796290874,33342369.48926596343517303,5974553.4759159330278635&CRS=EPSG:5650&WIDTH=2&HEIGHT=2&LAYERS=adv_alkis_flurstuecke&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&I=1&J=1&feature_count=100

I already tried setting a radius and/or buffer but without success.

Comment: A WMS is a picture of the data not a feature service, you need to look for a wfs endpoint

Comment: @IanTurton its a Map service yes. But with GetFeatureInfo you still get feature information of the point you clicked on the map. It's not like you only get a picture.

Comment: Do you know that there are many features on the queried layer at that location? Do you know if the service provider has customized their service when it comes to GetFeatureInfo?

Comment: GetCapabilities response for service (https://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/alkis_wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&) doesn't appear to be show one provided by GeoServer, so you should only assume standard WMS operations, so no buffer or radius parameters

Comment: You can't have an x/y (i/j) as zero, the value must be a pixel location in the GetMap response

Comment: @nmtoken Thats ture, my mistake sry. Its width/height 2 and x/y 1. Like in the request url. Changed it in the Question.